# JDBC driver returns extra rows in resultSet

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

So I am using JDBC template which can calls a procedure with filter and without filter. When called without filter JDBC should return 10 rows and when with filter it should return one result corresponding to that filter. But what's happening is when calling with filter  it returns 11 rows which are 10 rows which will be returned when the call us made without filter and 1 row with filter.

So basically if I called the procedure initially without filter  it returns 10 rows  and now I call the same procedure again with filter it will return all 10 rows that we're returned earlier plus filter row result. A third call will make it return 12 rows. At each call a row is being appended to resily set.

Please help me figure out where the error is

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to assist you with finding the error in your code when you don't provide the code that is causing the problem? **Perhaps**...in your `template.query()` you need to ensure the you are using `new ResultSetExtractor<whatever collection>()` (emphasis on **new**) or making sure your collection is cleared before making another call, for example: `List<StoreGoodies>.clear();` or List<StoreGoodies> list = new ArrayList<StoreGoodies>();`. Honestly, it's hard to say without seeing the code you are using. Edit your post and add the code you are using.